# Running Coded UI tests with Resharper/NUnit will not locate Silverlight components

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, nunit, coded-ui-tests

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Premium Edition. I've recorded tests with Coded UI, on a Silverlight application within a browser.

When I run the tests using  test runner they pass.
When I run them using NUnit, they open the browser and navigate on an HTML site properly, but once the test reaches the Silverlight application it fails to locate the elements.

Does anyone have any ideas?
This is the error message:
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException : The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'Silverlight'
ControlType:  'MainPageView'
  ----> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Answer on this post 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsautotest/thread/ef77627b-6802-44e3-928e-434f1901e152